# JavaScript Q. Works in FF&Safari, not IE7 or IE8

Tags: javascript

I have the following line of code:

```
<li>
    <label for="q2-1" onclick="setActive(this.id, 'question2-1-input');" id="q2-1-label"><input disabled="disabled" type="checkbox" name="question2" id="question2-1-input" value="1" />Opinions</label>
</li>
```

which calls:

```
function setActive(questionID, questionIDinput) 
{
    alert('setActive');
}
```

The above code works great in FF & Safari but not in IE. Is something above not IE friendly?

Thanks

Comment: Could you show more of your code ?

Comment: The problem must be somewhere else.

Comment: the code was hidden, fixed it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do not use "setActive". It is already taken (name of an existing function).
Replace it with something else (setActive1() will do ;)  ) and it will start working in IE as well.

Comment: That was it, thanks. I also noticed that LABEL had the INPUT wrapped inside which is sloppy, but that wasn't the cause.

Bad: <label><input></input></label>
Good: <label></label><input></input>

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you should put the `onclick` even on the `input` instead of the `label`.

Comment: it is perfectly fine to have an onclick for the label.
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_label.asp

Answer (score 0):

You should have the onclick event on the checkbox, not the label, the onclick event will be fired because you have the for="q2-1" on the label